# checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient - ruby gem mysql2 error (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install the `mysql2` gem (using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), and I get the following error when attempting to install the gem:

```
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

 Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
--with-mysql-dir
--without-mysql-dir
--with-mysql-include
--without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
--with-mysql-lib
--without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
--with-mysql-config
--without-mysql-config
--with-mysql-dir
--without-mysql-dir
--with-mysql-include
--without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
--with-mysql-lib
--without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mlib
--without-mlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-zlib
--without-zlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-socketlib
--without-socketlib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-nsllib
--without-nsllib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
--with-mygcclib
--without-mygcclib
--with-mysqlclientlib
--without-mysqlclientlib
 extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/nagaraju/nagu/sample/bundler20140511-2527-zimy7x/mysql2-0.3.15/gems/mysql2-0.3.15 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/nagaraju/nagu/sample/bundler20140511-2527-zimy7x/mysql2-0.3.15/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/mysql2-0.3.15/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.15), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.15'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Advance thanks..

Comment: On which machine you are installing?

Comment: am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Accept my answer by ticking the tick mark if it is helpful :)

Answer (score 9):

As you mentioned `Ubuntu 12.04`,try this before installing the `mysql2 gem`

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Just to note, that if you are connecting to a mysql server on a different machine, then the only package you need to install is `libmysqlclient-dev`